# Supporting IPv6-only clients in connecting to IPv4-only hosts

Tags: networking, domain-name-system, nat, ipv6

I have a service that aggregates third-party content, but ultimately end-users connect directly to the third parties they're interested in. The problem I'm facing is that many users are connecting over IPv6-only networks (in countries like India where this is more common). Many of the third-parties have IPv4-only hosts (no AAAA records or IPv6-compliant web servers). I cannot control the third-parties or re-host their content on an IPv6-compliant host.

Given these constraints, is there a way I can support IPv6-only clients in connecting directly or indirectly to an IPv4-only host? I've read of NAT64 and DNS64 as solutions for creating "synthetic" IPv6 addresses for IPv4 hosts, but it's not clear to me how such a solution could be implemented. I have the ability to redirect user traffic if need be, but it wouldn't be feasible to "proxy" the content by downloading it server-side and streaming it to the client. I'd also like to preserve the Client IP if possible, as hosts use this in part to identify unique clients.

Comment: Ultimately those other web sites must begin offering service on IPv6. There's virtually nothing you can do. Though, typically IPv6-only clients will have some sort of access to IPv4, usually through NAT64/DNS64 or large scale NAT provided by their ISP or mobile carrier. It's pretty uncommon for someone to have no access whatsoever to IPv4.

Comment: I'm told IPv6-only is the default configuration for Reliance Jio devices in India, although I don't have details on what exactly that means. One criteria for software on their platform is that it must fully support IPv6. Of course the challenge I have is with content I do not own or control. I could proxy connections through my IPv6-compliant host, but that gets very expensive and impacts host analytics as all traffic would then come from a single source.

Comment: AFAIK Reliance Jio uses NAT64 to provide access to IPv4 sites to their customers, mainly because that's what Apple requires for the iPhone. With NAT64 the device itself is IPv6-only and the translation is done by the ISP's NAT64 gateway. That's probably why you heard it was "IPv6-only". You don't have to do anything; they can still see IPv4 web sites, they just load a tiny bit slower. But that's a problem for those web sites to sort out (by offering IPv6).

Comment: In JioPhone device settings there's a "Data Settings" section for certain networks that lists "IPv4/IPv6" and "IPv6." The underlying OS, KaiOS, supports dual-stack. Perhaps JioPhones aren't configured to use Jio's NAT64 gateway, or perhaps they're unable to resolve DNS entries? I'm told all attempts to connect to IPv4-only hosts on JioPhone in IPv6 mode fail, although I realize it's difficult to debug with limited information.